# Mongoose - sort Date by date part only, ignoring time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection for the following model:

```
const VisitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    priority: { type: Number, min: 1, max: 3, required: true },
    datetime: { type: Date, required: true },
    // some other information
});
```

I'm trying to sort all documents in a way that the Visits closer to current date are shown before the later ones, but within a day, the ones with higher priority must be shown first.

For example: consider

`A (17-08-2018 14:00:00, P3)`

`B (17-08-2018 15:00:00, P2)`

`C (18-08-2018 15:00:00, P1)`

when sorting this, the desired response should be `[B, A, C]`, because on day `17-08-2018`, `B` has higher priority over `A` even though `A` is earlier and even if `C` has higher priority over both `A` and `B`, it is on a later day.

I'm looking for a way to sort firstly by `datetime`, but consider only the Date part and ignoring the Time, and later by `priority`. My current attempt considers the `datetime` entirely, giving me the wrong sorting:

```
Visit.find().sort('datetime priority')
```

**EDIT:** I know I can do it using `Array.sort()`. The question is upon doing it directly from `mongoose`, instead of retrieving the data and only then sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.6 for custom sort.

Use [`$dateFromParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) to compute date without time in  [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to keep the computed value as the extra field in the document followed by [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) sort on field.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-from-output-documents) with exclusion to drop the sort field to get expected output.

```
db.col.aggregate([
 {"$addFields":{
   "date":{
     "$dateFromParts":{
       "year":{"$year":"$datetime"},
       "month":{"$month":"$datetime"},
       "day":{"$dayOfMonth":"$datetime"}
      }
    }
 }}, 
 {"$sort":{"date":-1,"priority":1}},
 {"$project":{"date":0}}
])
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [**`$dateToString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) in mongodb **3.0** and above to convert your `datetime` into your desired format
and can easily [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) with the date

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "date": {
      { "$dateToString": {
        "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$datetime"
      }}
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "date": -1, "priority": 1 }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't convinced with any of the solutions I found, I kept digging and found "dateTrunc" function, compatible with Mongoose, a very clean solution, you can use it like this:

```
Project.aggregate([
{ $project : {
    updatedTrunc: {
      $dateTrunc: {
        date: "$updated",
        unit: "day",
        timezone: dateutil.PST_TZ
    }}
}}])
```

Since I noticed timezone was important to get the correct date, I'm passing in my timezone which is just a variable I have somewhere.

See this [reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/).